# Trying to implement singleton gives me stackoverflow error c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton

I am trying to make a singleton to account all the controllers I am going to create. When I run the website I get the stackoverflow error.
This is my singleton class:

```
public class MainController 
{
    private DatabaseController databaseController;
    private UserDBController userDBController;
    private static MainController MCinstance = null;
    public MainController()
    {
        if (MCinstance == null)
        {
            databaseController = new DatabaseController();
            userDBController = new UserDBController();
        }
    }
    public static MainController Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (MCinstance == null)
            {
                MCinstance = new MainController();
            }
            return MCinstance;
        }
    }
    public UserDBController GetUserDBController()
    {
        return userDBController;
    }
    public DatabaseController GetDBController()
    {
        return databaseController;
    }
}
```

This is how I use the singleton class in a different class:

```
private UserDBController userDBController = MainController.Instance.GetUserDBController();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code really does not force to use singleton. Developer unaware about this class would create new instance in order to operate on instance of MainController.

Comment: Use a synchronized method to prevent threading issues during lazy initialization

Comment: Do your `DatabaseController` or `UserDBController` constructors access `MainCotroller.Instance`?

Comment: The constructors? Nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your implemention like below,

```
public class MainController
{
    private DatabaseController databaseController;
    private UserDBController userDBController;
    private static MainController MCinstance = null;

    static MainController()
    {
        MCinstance = new MainController();
        MCinstance.databaseController = new DatabaseController();
        MCinstance.userDBController = new UserDBController();
    }

    public static MainController Instance
    {
        get
        {               
            return MCinstance;
        }
    }

    public UserDBController GetUserDBController()
    {
        return userDBController;
    }

    public DatabaseController GetDBController()
    {
        return databaseController;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `readonly` modifier to your `MCinstance` declaration and instantiate it only once in static constructor.

```
public class MainController 
{

    public static readonly MainController Instance = null;
    static MainController()
    {
        Instance  = new MainController()
    }
}
```

Comment: And where would I then call the constructor?

Comment: @user2014780 You don't need to. The CLR will invoke the static constructor automatically the first time you access any static member of the class, ej: MainController.Instance

Answer (score 0):

For singleton use need to use private constructor. And move code of private construct in the place where instance is creating.

```
    public class MainController 
    {
        private DatabaseController databaseController = new DatabaseController();
        private UserDBController userDBController = new UserDBController();
        private static MainController MCinstance = null;
        private MainController()
        {

        }
        public static MainController Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (MCinstance == null)
                {
                    MCinstance = new MainController();
                }
                return MCinstance;
            }
        }
        public UserDBController GetUserDBController()
        {
            return userDBController;
        }
        public DatabaseController GetDBController()
        {
            return databaseController;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That will not compile. You can't access instance fields in static member.

Comment: Yes make thiose variable static

Comment: Why? Why would you suggest to make fields static. Are you sure what you mean?

Comment: Check out I have make updation. But you need private constructor for singleton

Comment: Asking for votes isn't welcome. This is not a election. If we feel your answer is good, we'll upvote you. But, it isn't. Question itself isn't reproducing the problem specified, and your answer solves nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this is the only code you need by making use of static classes in C#. The constructor is not public, since it is automatically called the first time you use this class. This class only has one instance.

```
public static class MainController 
{
    private static DatabaseController databaseController;
    private static UserDBController userDBController;

    static MainController()
    {
        databaseController = new DatabaseController();
        userDBController = new UserDBController();
    }

    public static UserDBController GetUserDBController()
    {
        return userDBController;
    }
    public static DatabaseController GetDBController()
    {
        return databaseController;
    }
}
```